# Product details page layout problem, magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, page-layouts

In magento 2,  Product detail page is coming with different layout, some product render with 1 page column while some with 2 column, i saved all product in admin for NO LAYOUT but its not working, how to resolve this. I need 1 column layout only.
I am using Magento ver. 2.0.7

Answer (score 1):

At magento, **top most priority is Db** values.

So, If you will  saved all product in ***admin for 1Column then it may be work's***
Note: that after apply, you need **to  flush cache**.

If it is not work then there are ***should be some observer*** which **change pay layout**

### **Solution**

for this case, you can use event `layout_generate_blocks_before`,using this event you can `change pagelayout`

### Observer

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ObserverChangeLayoutForProductview implements ObserverInterface
{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $_actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;


    private $_pageConfig;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig     
    ) {
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
         $this->_pageConfig = $pageConfig; 
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $full_action_name = $observer->getFullActionName();

        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        if($full_action_name == 'catalog_product_view'){
            //print_r($layout->getBlock('head')->getRobots());
            $this->_pageConfig->setPageLayout('1column');
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `catalog_product_view.xml` in your module and add below code.

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 </page>
```